# I`m trying to make regular expression reader function. C++

Tags: c++, regex

I have line with few words and want to place those words in vector so I can manipulate with each word as a separate object. the problem is when I use function regexp_search(string,match,regexp) after finding first match I`m trying to delete everything what was in string before found match word but calling function match.suffinx().str() returns emply string when it should return other words from that string.

here is my regular expression :

```
std::regex reg("([C-Fc-f]at)");
```

here is my function :

```
std::vector<string> stringToVector(string str, regex reg){
cout << boolalpha;
vector<string> vec;
smatch match;


while (regex_search(str, match, reg))
{
    vec.push_back(match.str(1));
    str = match.suffix().str();
}
return vec;}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample strings, along with the expected sub-strings to be pushed back onto the vector?

Comment: ye for example I paste string : "Cat fat rat bat" function pushes "Cat" inside of vector but suffix of match after that is equal to "" (empty  string) that`s why function stops working and doesn`t push "fat" inside vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine.  For testing purposes, I first amended your function to output the results...

```
std::vector<std::string> stringToVector(std::string str, std::regex reg) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::smatch match;

    while (std::regex_search(str, match, reg))
    {
        std::cout << "Match\n";
        std::cout << "match.str() = " << match.str() << '\n';
        std::cout << "match.suffix() = " << match.suffix() << '\n';

        vec.push_back(match.str());
        str = match.suffix();
        std::cout << "str = " << str << "'\n\n";
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Then in `Main`, I called `stringToVector` and printed the results...

```
std::regex reg("([C-Fc-f]at)");

std::vector<std::string> v;
v = stringToVector("Cat fat rat bat", reg);

for (auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)
{
    std::cout << *itr << '\n';
}
```

Here's the output...

```
Match
match.str() = Cat
match.suffix() =  fat rat bat
str =  fat rat bat'

Match
match.str() = fat
match.suffix() =  rat bat
str =  rat bat'

Cat
fat
```

Comment: okay I tried the code you wrote and it words, the probles is when I try to enter string by using standart in stream ( std::cin ) when I make a string and paste it in this function it doestn`t work. Now I`m trying to figure it out what is the difference between inserting text by std::cin and just wrintg string in code...

Comment: owww I got it, I feel soooo dumb rigtht now, the answer is when I use std::cin it gets words untill first space sign and that`s why it can only get first word the solution is just to use std::getLine